# Webpack 2 asset optimization UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Error: UNKNOWN

Tags: node.js, webpack-2

When running webpack on my local development machine (Windows 7) it runs perfectly with the following output snippet:

```
69% building modules 495/496 modules 1 active ...urce\node_modules\rxjs\util\as
 69% building modules 495/497 modules 2 active ...node_modules\rxjs\util\MapPoly
 69% building modules 496/497 modules 1 active ...node_modules\rxjs\util\MapPoly
Hash: 85a3bcdc12917bd4a806
Version: webpack 2.4.1
Time: 15364ms
                                       Asset       Size  Chunks
   Chunk Names
polyfills.99a4edee559bb24fa991.bundle.js.map     212 kB       1  [emitted]
   polyfills
                                  0.chunk.js    10.5 kB       0  [emitted]

         main.b9ea70169875a065e3ac.bundle.js      43 kB       2  [emitted]
```

This is the same correct output for several other machines in the office. However, when running the same task on the build server (Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter) I get:

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error**

```
 69% building modules 495/496 modules 1 active ...urce\node_modules\rxjs\util\as
 69% building modules 495/497 modules 2 active ...node_modules\rxjs\util\MapPoly
 69% building modules 496/497 modules 1 active ...node_modules\rxjs\util\MapPoly
 94% asset optimization(node:2116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled p
romise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, stat 'E:\svn\
SLS\Trunk\Kaleida.SLS.SPASource\src\assets'
```

The error doesn't tell me much and I've searched over and over online and on stackoverflow but can't find any information on this exact problem.

I've double-checked that NodeJS, npm and Webpack are all installed with the same versions in both environments. I've ensured that I'm running as administrator and that everyone has full control permissions to the directory.

Help!